# What is this device wired up to my garage door?

Tags: garage-door

There is something wired to my garage door (at least the wire colors are the same as the ones for the door sensors), mounted on the wall near the ceiling.

[image]

What is this? I cannot find any mention of it in [garage door component diagrams](https://www.bayviewwindows.ca/images_blog/anatomy-of-a-garage-door.jpg).

Comment: What wire terminals on the garage door opener is it connected to, and what make and model is your garage door opener?

Comment: Looks like a transformer for your doorbell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks to be a doorbell transformer. But I've never seen one used in conjunction with a garage door opener. Do you perhaps have a doorbell in your garage?

Comment: There is only one doorbell inside, but it is right as you walk in from the garage door. Pulling off the panel from the bell, the wire colors matched as well. Doing a little more digging now that it was more clear what it was, I also checked behind the doorbell & there wasn't a transformer tucked behind it, so I'm certain that the one in the garage is the transformer for the doorbell now, and the wires matching the garage door opener must have been a coincidence. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The person who installed probably had leftover wire from the garage door opener and used it. It's wire all the same 